# File Extensions to Include rather than Exclude - Subversion

Tags: svn, controls, version

I know I can setup an exclude list with subversion, but is it possible to do an include list instead?

I am trying to add a financial dataset into version control to track changes to only specific types of files.  It is impossible to create an exclusion list as users can add any types of files to the dataset.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using TortoiseSVN or command client for Subversion? It may help to make a possible answer more concrete.

Comment: I am trying to ultimately do everything from the command line.  I will end up using something like Jenkins to batch the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn st | grep extension | sed -En 's/^(M|A)[ ]+(.+)/\2/p' > targets.txt
```

Then

```
svn commit --targets targets.txt
```

Then

```
rm targets.txt
```

It'd also be easy enough to write a bash script to take the extension as a parameter.